# Sign up with Facebook integration using jsf spring and spring security

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-security, spring-social

Am developing a web application using JSF, Spring and Spring Security. I have a requirement i.e **Integrate with Facebook and linked-in for sign up and sign in process**. how can i achieve this by using spring security and JSF integration. google it i found tightly integrated with spring MVC but am using JSF MVC. can please help me how can i achieve this by using JSF and Spring Security.

Thanks & Regards
Ravindra